# Parse Config getting error "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: parse-platform

I'm getting this error when trying to make any changes in Parse config. So I have to wait Parse team to fix this or are there any solutions?

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook team is fixing this issue, we can do nothing here.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/888924084482394/